# Finding complexity of nested loops

Tags: algorithm, math

so I have this really complex nested loop that I need to find the complexity of. The code is given below:

```java
1. int c = 0;
2. for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
3.   for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
4.     for (int k = 1; k <= i + j; k += 3)
5.       c++;
6. return c;
```

So I know that the complexity is in **O(n^3)**, but I need to know how to mathematically prove. Below shows the frequency of execution of each line.

```
1. 1
2. n
3. n(n-1)
4. No idea how to do this
5. No idea
6. 1
```

Can someone please help me out with the 4th and 5th step? It is really confusing as k goes from 1 to (i+j).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 4:

```
i is O(n).
j is O(n).
Therefore, i+j is O(n).
Having a constant step of 3, making (i+j)/3 steps, is O(n).
This inner loop will run for n*n*k iterations, where
    k is the summation of ceil[(i+j)3] over their ranges.
    k will be roughly (n+2)/3.
```

Line 5:

```
Increment is O(1).
```

That should finish your derivation.

Comment: Shouldn't the kth loop run for n(n-1)(2n/3)? Because the jth loop runs for (n-1) times right?

Comment: (1) That difference does not affect the computational complexity; (2) No, `i` and `j` have the same iteration limits.

Comment: Well if this is true, then for n=5, the value of c is 83 (from n*n*(2n/3)). But when I run the code, the value of c is 58. Could you please let me know what I'm missing out on?

Comment: You're missing that I made a computational error.  Adjusting my answer ...

Comment: Most of all, why are you concerning yourself with the exact value of `c`?  Your question asks about the computational complexity, which is the limit of time increase as a function of `n`,  `c` is a reasonable metric of time, but the specific value for small `n` is not something over which to lose study time.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove the complexity mathematically. The total number of iterations can be represented like (unfortunately latex is not supported)

```
sum_j=1^n sum_i=1^n (i + j) / 3
```

If you draw up the grid of `i` and `j` values and their sum `i + j`, you can see this too.

This is equivalent to

```
sum_j=1^n {[n(n + 1)/2 + nj] / 3}
```

Which can be further simplified to

```
{n[n(n + 1)/2] + n[n(n + 1)/2] / 3}
```

Which after evaluation gives

```
(n^3 + n^2) / 3
```

And this is of the order `O(n^3)`.

The number of iterations with step being 1 instead of 3 can be proven programmatically (code in Python)

```py
c = 0
n = 4 # change n for testing, slow
for i in range(1, n + 1):
  for j in range(1, n + 1):
    for k in range(1, i + j + 1):
      c += 1
assert(c == (n ** 3 + n ** 2))
```

Comment: That said, dividing the iterations by 3 isn't exactly "correct" since it's more of a `floor` function, but my math can't handle that.

Comment: Well if this is true, then for n=5, the value of c is 100. But when I run the code, the value of c is 58. Could you please let me know what I'm missing out on?

Comment: @ppaloo Your code runs `k` in steps of *3*. The "proof" program is for `k` in steps of *1*, since the sum `i + j` can never always be a perfect multiple of 3. It's difficult to construct an exact mathematical proof with a floor function.

Comment: @ppaloo Anyway for `n = 5` the value of `c` is 150 not 100.

Comment: On further thought, it might be a `ceiling` function instead. The reason for `c` not being exact is the same though. You can only estimate.

Answer (score 0):

The program does for each `(i,j) ∈ [n] X [n]` a `O(i+j)` operation.
We can say it's a `O(i)` operation and then `O(j)` operation and the complexity remains the same.
Thus, for each `i` we do `O(n*i)` [for each `j` (`n` times), we do `O(i)`] and `O(1 + 2 + ... + n) = O(n^2)`. Obviously, `O(n*i) + O(n^2) = O(n^2)` and we do this `n` times for a total of `O(n^3).`

Answer (score 0):

Since the only thing we care about is the O complexity, this can be transformed as long as we are within constant factors:

1) `k += 3` =>  `k++` changes runtime with a constant factor between [1, 3];

2) `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` => `for (int i = n/2; i <= n; i++)`: constant factor between [0.5, 1];

3) `for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)` => `for (int j = n/2; j <= n; j++)`: constant factor between [0.5, 1];

4) now `i + j` is between n and 2n, so `for (int k = 1; k <= i + j; k += 3)` => `for (int k = 1; k <= n; k += 3)`: constant factor between [0.5, 1].

After these, the program is transformed as:

```java
1. int c = 0;
2. for (int i = n/2; i <= n; i++)
3.   for (int j = n/2; j <= n; j++)
4.     for (int k = 1; k <= n; k ++)
5.       c++;
6. return c;
```

And it's easy to see `c == n ** 3 / 4`, which means the transformed program has a complexity of O(n^3).

Note this also proves the program runs within Ɵ(n^3).